# Flash Builder Photoshop Extension

Tags: extension-methods

I want to pass two arguments with different data types in same function.  But the problem is, I want to call the function (runScript) and pass the 2nd argument in both int and array. I called following function

```
Public var StrArray:Array;
<S:Button click="runScript('Name',150)" />
<S:Button click="runScript('Name',StrArray) />

public function runScript(arg1:String,arg2:int):void{

}
```

I want to recall the `runScript` function.